# It is possible to have a multi line tab group in Aptana Studio

Tags: tabs, aptana

I often work with many files open and would prefer a way to show all of the tabs in the tab group (mine is currently at the top) to be able to select the appropriate file to edit.

Comment: no its not so went to php storm instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to do this in Aptana